# CRM javascript button calls json url and parse a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, crm

I am creating a button in javascript (I can't create it using HTML - system limitation) and I want this button to go to a certain url (REST - getting JSON file). Afterwards, I'd like to display an alert with the value from that file and/or save the value from JSON file on a page where the button is placed. So far, I figured how to call the REST URI. Could anyone help me move forward with that?

```
<script>
oraclecrmod.onReady(function() {
if(oraclecrmod.ctx.isObject("Account") && oraclecrmod.ctx.isDetailPage()) {

var on_click = function httpGet("https://example.crmondemand.com/OnDemand/user/Rest/027/Accounts")
{
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "https://example.crmondemand.com/OnDemand/user/Rest/027/Accounts", false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

// Read the "Test Read" button on the main Account TitleBar
var tb = oraclecrmod.getTitleBar("AccountFormTB");
var bt = oraclecrmod.createButton({
id:"TestBtn",
text:"Test Read",
parent:tb
});
bt.on("click",on_click);
}
});
</script>
```

Is this better? How can I improve it? It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you navigate to another page, your current JavaScript will stop executing. The current Document gets unloaded when you navigate pages.

See the HTML5 spec for more details: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface